# How to store values with same memory location in c?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

If I have a file stream with content

```
123 1234

1223 124235

21432 325
```

In my program I read line by line of the file and store the first target of each line into my list. These line with same location and when I run the program it will keep pointing to the most recent data and place it in to list. Which means If I have a function called printL() in while loop. It will print

```
123/

1223/1223/

21432/21432/21432/
```

instead of

```
123/

123/1223/

123/1223/21432
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct n{
  char *value;
  struct n *next;
} Node;


void printList(Node *head){
  Node *cur = head;
  while(cur!=NULL){
    printf("%s/", cur->value);
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void insertIntoList(Node **head, char *data){
  Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if (newNode == NULL){
    perror("Failed to allocate a new node for the linked list");
    exit(1);
  }
  newNode->value = data;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  Node *currentList = *head;
  if(*head == NULL){    //if the linked list head is null, then add the target into linked list
    *head = newNode;
  }
  else{
    while(currentList->next!=NULL){
      currentList = currentList->next;
    }
    currentList->next = newNode;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char**argv){
  FILE *fileStream;


  size_t len = 0;
  char *line = NULL;
  Node *head = NULL;


  int j;
  for(j=1; j<argc-2;j++){
    fileStream = fopen(argv[j], "r");
    if(fileStream == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "could not open");
      continue;
    }
    insertIntoList(&head,"a"); /////////////Line 95
    insertIntoList(&head,"b");
    insertIntoList(&head,"c"); 
    insertIntoList(&head,"d");
    printf("here is a try\n");
    printList(head);
    while(getline(&line, &len, fileStream)!=EOF){ /////////////Line 101
            char *targetNum = strtok(line, " \t\r\n");
            printf("*****%s\n", targetNum);
            insertIntoList(&head, targetNum);
            printf("######print head here is##########\n");
          printList(head);
          printf("######print head here is##########->\n");
      }
      //printList(head);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @MordechayS How should I store the values...It prints the current value such as "21432/21432/21432/" instead of "123/1223/21432"...I don't know how to store the pointed value...

Comment: Add the 'insertIntoList' code, please.

Comment: @MordechayS insert function added... In main function I tested insertIntoList(&head,"a");insertIntoList(&head,"b"); and so on..And it can printed a/b/.. successfully but for the content in the file..The insert does not work. The pointer always pointed to the recent one..

Comment: @HxH because the output shows 3 times the same value, the problem is certainly due to the use of the same variable char *line as input of strtok().

Comment: @J.Piquard But why? When it calls getline in while loop, does the current line pass into char*line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the content of each loaded field returned from `strtok()`, just add a `strdup()` before calling `insertIntoList()` after checking if not a null-pointer.

> In your code, if you compare the value of both `line` and `targetNum`
>   are the same. If fact, the `strtok()` function returns a pointer to
>   the input string and keep the pointer for the next argument.

Replace the following code:

```
    char *targetNum = strtok(line, " \t\r\n");
    printf("*****%s\n", targetNum);
    insertIntoList(&head, targetNum);
```

By that one:

```
    char *targetNum = strtok(line, " \t\r\n");
    if (targetNum != NULL) {
        printf("*****%s\n", targetNum);
        insertIntoList(&head, strdup(targetNum));
    }
```

Comment: I am thinking strdup() is a function which can malloc space for you. When you call this function, how do you free it? When I try to add char *temp = strdup(targetNum) and insertIntoList(&head, temp); I added free(temp) after, but it got memory leak when I use valgrind debugging

Comment: @HxH Yes, the `strdup()` function is an equivalent to `malloc()`+`strcpy()` and you have to call one `free()` for each `strdup()` call. But in your function `insertIntoList()` there is another call to malloc() for the structure `Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));` which needs also to be freed. And because your source code doesn't have a `fclose()` call you could have also another memory leak. So, the best is to open an new question with your updated source code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't store the contents of the string in your list nodes; you store a pointer to the buffer used for the contents of the string.

Consider changing your list node structure to

```
typedef  struct node  Node;
struct node {
    Node *next;
    char  data[];
};
```

where the contents of the string are stored in the C99 flexible array member.

Your node constructor is then something like

```
Node *new_node(const char *data)
{
    const size_t  datalen = (data) ? strlen(data) : 0;
    Node         *result;

    result = malloc(sizeof (Node) + datalen + 1);
    if (!result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (datalen > 0)
        memcpy(result->data, data, datalen);

    result->next = NULL;
    result->data[datalen] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

See how the function allocates memory for the copy of the data?

Personally, I prefer something like

```
typedef  struct node  Node;
struct node {
    Node   *next;
    size_t  hash;
    size_t  size;
    char    data[];
};
```

where the `size` member is basically `strlen(data)` (except that you can also use the nodes to hold binary data that includes nul bytes `\0`), and `hash` is a simple [hash](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) computed from `data`. `hash` is useful if you intend to compare the entire contents of nodes; if two nodes' lengths or hashes differ, then it is certain their contents differ; if they are the same, *then* you compare them character by character (`memcmp(node1->data, node2->data, node1->length) == 0` if they are the same).

The constructor for the above is something like (using DJB2 hash):

```
Node *new_node(Node *next, const void *data, const size_t size)
{
    Node *result;

    result = malloc(sizeof (Node) + size + 1);
    if (!result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "new_node(): Out of memory (%zu bytes)\n", size);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Copy and hash data using DJB2 hash (not that good, but fast) */
    {
        unsigned char       *src = (unsigned char *)data;
        unsigned char *const end = (unsigned char *)data + size;
        unsigned char       *dst = result->data;
        size_t               hash = 5381;

        while (src < end) {
            hash = hash * 33 + (size_t)(*src);
            *(dst++) = *(src++);
        }

        /* Add terminator */
        *dst = '\0';
    }

    result->next = next;
    result->hash = hash;
    result->size = size;

    return result;
}
```

These `Node`s can also be used in e.g. hash tables, which makes the type quite versatile.